# How to insert data from tableWidget into sqlite Database

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to insert tableWidget data into SQLite db.

1) Total number of columns in a row are 9, If the table has less than 9 items data, for example: if table has items in date, name, location and item1, it shows an error like this:

> item2 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 4).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

2) If table has 9 items, no error but data is not inserted into the db.

```
date = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 0).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
name = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 1).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]

location = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 2).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
item1 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 3).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
item2 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 4).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
item3 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 5).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
item4 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 6).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
item5 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 7).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
item6 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 8).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount())]
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute("INSERT INTO maintable(date,name,location,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6) \
     VALUES ('%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" %(''.join(date),
                                                                     ''.join(name),
                                                                     ''.join(location),
                                                                     ''.join(item1),
                                                                     ''.join(item2),
                                                                     ''.join(item3),
                                                                     ''.join(item4),
                                                                     ''.join(item5),
                                                                     ''.join(item6)))
```

[qTableWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB84O.jpg)

Comment: Please be careful with the formatting of your questions. Read the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to better understand how to write questions and insert code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an item is empty, `item()` will return `None`; you can check if the item exists within the comprehension:

```
item2 = [self.tableWidget.item(row, 4).text() for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()) if self.tableWidget.item(row,4)]
# ...
```

But this is not very readable nor really optimized, as it will call `item()` twice for each row.
I'd suggest to use a function that returns the list based on the column:

```
def getColumn(self, column):
    data = []
    for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        item = self.tableWidget.item(row, column)
        if item:
            data.append(item.text())
    return ''.join(data)

def writeToDatabase(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO \
        maintable(date,name,location,item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6) \
        VALUES ('{}', '{}','{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}') \
        ".format(*[self.getColumn(c) for c in range(9)]))
    # if you don't call commit(), the data is not stored
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: I Added **self.updatebtn.clicked.connect(self.getColumn)**  to connect **def getColumn(self, column):** and its nothing doing when i am clicked on the button, and added **self.writeToDatabase()**  before **def writeToDatabase(self):** to connect from ** def getColumn(self, column):**. For reference  i added ****print(data)** after **return ''.join(data)** to check the status.but not printing.  please find the snapshot named  qTableWidget. at the Question section.

Comment: Why did you connect the clicked signal to `getColumn()`? It doesn't make any sense, that function is just a commodity that is used within `writeToDatabase()`, and that's the function you should connect to. Also, if you added a print statement **after** the return, it won't work anyway (it's called `return` for a reason...).